# PMF of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, self-learning

X and Y are independent and geometrically distributed random variables with 
$$
P(X = m) = p(1-p)^{m}, m=0,1,2...
$$
$$ 
P(Y = n) = p(1-p)^{n}, n=0,1,2...
$$
To find the probability mass function (PMF) of Z= X+Y, I should find the moment-generating function of Z 
$$
M_{Z} = M_{X}M_{Y} = \left (\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^{t}}\right)^2
$$

My question is: How to find the PMF of $M_{Z}$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $X+Y=z$ if $X=0$ and $Y=z$, or $X=1$ and $Y=z-1$, and so on up to $X=z$ and $Y=0$.
Thus 
$$\Pr(Z=z)=\sum_{k=0}^z p(1-p)^k p(1-p)^{z-k}.$$
This simplifies to 
$$\sum_{k=0}^z p^2(1-p)^z.$$
This simplifies to $(z+1)p^2(1-p)^z$.

**Remark:** We can use the moment-generating function approach. However, once we have found the mgf, we need to identify the distribution. That is easy only if we have a "dictionary" of moment-generating functions.

A sum of independent geometric random variables with the same "$p$" has *negative binomial* distribution. It is the number of "failures" until the $n$-th success. 
The probability that this sum is equal to $z$ is equal to
$$\binom{z+1}{n-1}p^{n-1}(1-p)^{(z+1)-(n-1)}p.$$
For we must have exactly $n-1$ successes in the first $z+1$ trials, and then a success. Ours is the case $n=2$.